# How to write similar test cases without breaking the Single Responsibility Principle?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tdd, solid-principles, single-responsibility-principle

I have created one unit test for different inputs, to make sure the outputs are correct.

```
[TestMethod]
    public void CountInversionTest()
    {
        #region Arrange
        int[] sourceArray = {4, 3, 2, 1};
        int correctInversionCount = 6;
        int[] sourceArray2 = { 1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6};
        int correctInversionCount2 = 3;
        int[] sourceArray3 = { 5, 6, 2, 3, 1, 4, 7 };
        int correctInversionCount3 = 10;
        #endregion

        #region Act
        Sorter sorter = new Sorter();
        int inversionCount = sorter.CountInversion(sourceArray);
        int inversionCount2 = sorter.CountInversion(sourceArray2);
        int inversionCount3 = sorter.CountInversion(sourceArray3);
        #endregion

        #region Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(correctInversionCount, inversionCount);
        Assert.AreEqual(correctInversionCount2, inversionCount2);
        Assert.AreEqual(correctInversionCount3, inversionCount3);
        #endregion
    }
```

Because the cases are very similar, I put them in one test method. Is that behavior okay or does it break the Single Responsibility Principle? If it breaks SRP, what is a better solution?

Comment: You usually want to have them in separate tests so it's easier to know which test failed.

Comment: @itsme86 Should I create a different TestMethod for every case of them? if so What should be a proper naming convention for these TestMethods? 
And wouldn't that be repeating myself?

Comment: Why do you want to test 3 cases? Is there any special edge case tested by one of them? If so, put the purpose in the name of a separate testcase.

Comment: If you're doing the same thing in all 3 cases, testing frameworks usually let you decorate the method with attributes to pass in a parameter. For example, the test method could accept an array and the attribute would define the arrays to pass in. For instance, check this out: https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/TestCase-Attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I decided to answer my own question**

So as I am not using any third party framework or library for test, instead I am using the default MSTest.
I ended up doing this

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void CountInversionTestCase1()
    {
        CountInversionTest(new int[] { 4, 3, 2, 1 }, 6);
    }
    [TestMethod]
    public void CountInversionTestCase2()
    {
        CountInversionTest(new int[] { 1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6 }, 3);
    }
    [TestMethod]
    public void CountInversionTestCase3()
    {
        CountInversionTest(new int[] { 5, 6, 2, 3, 1, 4, 7 }, 10);
    }

    public void CountInversionTest(int[] sourceArray, int expectedInversionCount)
    {
        #region Act
        Sorter sorter = new Sorter();
        long actualInversionCount = sorter.CountInversion(sourceArray);
        #endregion

        #region Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedInversionCount, actualInversionCount);
        #endregion
    }
```

Which is not the best solution out there, but it satisfies the requirements and doesn't use any third party library. 
I hope it helps anyone out there.

Comment: It would be better to give meaningful names to the test methods, rather than `Case1`, `Case2`, `Case3`. Give them names that indicate _why_ three cases are necessary, i.e. what part of the `CountInversion()` method does each case cover that isn't covered by the other cases.

Answer (score 5):

With a proper unit testing framework like [xUnit.net](https://xunit.github.io/), you could write a [Parameterized Test](http://xunitpatterns.com/Parameterized%20Test.html) instead:

```
[Theory]
[InlineData(new[] { 4, 3, 2, 1 }, 6)]
[InlineData(new[] { 1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6 }, 3)]
[InlineData(new[] { 5, 6, 2, 3, 1, 4, 7 }, 10)]
public void ParameterizedCountInversionTest(int[] input, int expected)
{
    Sorter sut = new Sorter();
    var actual = sut.CountInversion(input);
    Assert.Equal(expected, actual);
}
```

This will run three tests, instead of one, giving you better visibility into which particular test case failed (if any fails).

The test is also more readable like this.

[NUnit](http://www.nunit.org) also has this feature, but MSTest doesn't (last time I looked).

Answer (score 1):

The Single Responsibility Principle tells us that this method should have only one reason to change. So a unit test should test one method and should only change when the method-under-test changes. Here that would be the `CountInversion()` method. Could the `CountInversion()` method change in such a way that one of the `sourceArray` inputs would have to change but not the others? In that case, the inputs should be split into separate tests to accommodate SRP.

Generally, it's fine for one unit test to call the method-under-test multiple times with different inputs. As @itsme86 commented, testing frameworks typically facilitate such behavior by passing arguments to the unit test.